# XML getting wrong UTF encoding

Tags: xml, utf-8, byte, utf, stringwriter

I am trying to encode my xml text using utf-8 with the code below. For some reason I am getting utf-16 instead of utf-8. Any reason why please?

```
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        xdoc.Save(writer);
        writer.Flush();
        string xml = writer.ToString();
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(pathDesktop + "\\22CRE002.XPO", bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

`StringWriter` itself "advertises" (via the [`TextWriter.Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.encoding.aspx) property) an encoding of UTF-16, so the `XmlWriter` detects that and modifies the XML declaration accordingly. You are actually writing out the data as UTF-8 - it's just that the XML file itself will claim (incorrectly) that it's UTF-16, leading to all kinds of errors.

Your options are:

- Use a subclass of `StringWriter` which advertises a different encoding by overriding the `Encoding` property
- Just bypass the `StringWriter` entirely and write straight to the file.

Personally I'd go with the second option:

```
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(Path.Combine(pathDesktop, "22CRE002.XPO"))
{
    xdoc.Save(writer);
}
```

Why buffer it all in memory first? Note that `XmlWriter` will already default to UTF-8 if you don't specify an encoding.

Comment: so should I have something like this ?

using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(Path.Combine(pathDesktop, "22CRE002.XPO"))
{
    xdoc.Save(writer);
}

writer.Flush();
            string xml = writer.ToString();
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(pathDesktop + "\\22CRE002.XPO", bytes);

Please specify thanks a lot

Comment: ohh sorry for the code :/ can you give me how will the code be emended regarding my code from the question

Comment: @MarkFenech: No, the code I've given you is the *complete* code. Don't use the StringWriter at all. If you really need it in a string, please explain why - you haven't really specified your requirements

Comment: Sure ok sorry than...I have a problem when loading files that I am getting some hidden characters and when I loaded the file with string I didnt get those hidden characters, so kinda problem solved but now im getting this utf 16 problem. Refer to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917838/xml-hidden-characters-how-to-remove-bom

Comment: @MarkFenech: I've answered the other question. In future, please give appropriate context from the start - if you'd included a link to the previous question before, I'd have just answered that one and added a comment in this one, rather than answering it separately.