# Laravel: XML Parsing Fatal Error at Line 1, Column 1: Content is not allowed in prolog. Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: php, xml, laravel, xml-parsing, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am trying to post product in Amazon Seller account with Laravel. But I am getting error:
**XML Parsing Fatal Error at Line 1, Column 1: Content is not allowed in prolog. Content is not allowed in prolog.** This is my code, so if someone can help me to solve this.

```
$requestXml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
          <Header>
            <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
            <MerchantIdentifier>Myid</MerchantIdentifier>
          </Header>
          <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
          <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
          <Message>
            <MessageID>1</MessageID>
            <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
            <Product>
              <SKU>56789</SKU>
              <StandardProductID>
                <Type>ASIN</Type>
                <Value>B0EXAMPLEG</Value>
              </StandardProductID>
              <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
              <DescriptionData>
                <Title>Example Product Title</Title>
                <Brand>Example Product Brand</Brand>
                <Description>This is an example product description.</Description>
                <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 1</BulletPoint>
                <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 2</BulletPoint>
                <MSRP currency="USD">25.19</MSRP>
                <Manufacturer>Example Product Manufacturer</Manufacturer>
                <ItemType>example-item-type</ItemType>
              </DescriptionData>
              <ProductData>
                <Health>
                  <ProductType>
                    <HealthMisc>
                      <Ingredients>Example Ingredients</Ingredients>
                      <Directions>Example Directions</Directions>
                    </HealthMisc>
                  </ProductType>
                </Health>
              </ProductData>
            </Product>
          </Message>
        </AmazonEnvelope>';

      /*$requestXml=preg_replace('/^([^\w<]+)</', '<', $requestXml);*/
      // $requestXml = trim($requestXml);
      $requestXml = preg_replace('/[[:^print:]]/', '', $requestXml);


      Log::channel('amazon')->info('Amazon create feed request: ', ['request' => $requestXml]);


      $response = Http::withHeaders([
        'Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8'
      ])->put($url, [
            'body' => $requestXml
          ]);
```

Comment: You're doing lots of preprocessing, it'd be useful to know why. [utf8_encode()](https://php.net/utf8_encode) is used when source data is ISO-8859-1, is that really the case? What exact characters do you want to strip and why?

Comment: Hi, this is xml example fromhttps://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/feeds-api-v2021-06-30-use-case-guide#step-3-upload-the-feed-data even if I remove utf8_encode($requestXml) and leave just $requestXml it sazs same error

Comment: That link doesn't answer any of my questions, neither did you. We are in 2023, you'll only find ISO-8859-1 in legacy systems. Is your system legacy or not? Why do you create XML and then try to "fix" it in the next line?

Comment: Not to mention that `uft8_encode()` is now deprecated. Don't use it.

Comment: Very possible that your real XML has invisible Byte Order Mark (BOM) at the very beginning of the XML prolog. Please try to remove the BOM. Notepad++ can show BOM in the status bar at the bottom right, something like **UTF-8-BOM**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917838/xml-hidden-characters-how-to-remove-bom

Comment: I already tried like this prefixAmazon = Storage::disk('amazon')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix();
    $requestXml = file_get_contents($prefixAmazon . 'createFeed.xml') and put xml code in this file but same error

Answer (score 0):

I have revised your code for validating string and hidden characters please try this one and also I have removed utf8_encode function as your XML string is already in UTF-8 :

```
$requestXml = trim($requestXml); // Remove whitespace from the beginning and end of the XML string
$requestXml = preg_replace('/[[:^print:]]/', '', $requestXml); 

// Log the XML request after cleaning it
Log::channel('amazon')->info('Amazon create feed request: ', ['request' => $requestXml]);

$response = Http::withHeaders([
  'Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8'
])->put($url, [
  'body' => $requestXml
]);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help but it didn't work, I tried now and still the same error, I am really not sure what is wrong..

Comment: Have you validated your XML file? if not, You can use an online validator tool to find hidden issues.

Comment: Yes, it is valid XML. I checked.

Comment: XML is defined in the source code, it's impossible to say whether it's UTF-8 unless you have access to the source file. And, what hidden characters can there possibly be?

Comment: I already tried like this prefixAmazon = Storage::disk('amazon')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix();
    $requestXml = file_get_contents($prefixAmazon . 'createFeed.xml') and put xml code in this file but same error